# How can manage Azure Table with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure

I already search for this but i can't get it to work.
I already have access to the Table Storage and list all tables.
How can I do now to update a row in a specific Table in Azure using Powershell?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure powershell + azure storage api solution:

https://github.com/chriseyre2000/Powershell/tree/master/Azure2

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Cerebrata Azure Management Cmdlets (http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets) which has Cmdlets to manage Windows Azure Storage. Other alternative is to consume Storage Client Library in PowerShell. Please look at this thread for an example: [How do I change the timeout value for Add-Blob Azure cmdlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976896/how-do-i-change-the-timeout-value-for-add-blob-azure-cmdlet/12986393#12986393) though it is for uploading blobs with a timeout value but it should give you an idea about consuming storage client library in PowerShell.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the Pipeworks library http://powershellpipeworks.com/

Follow the connecting the clouds examples.